# Gluon-Mobile, No fonts on Android 8.0 (Oreo) OnePlus5T phone

Tags: android, gluon, gluon-mobile

Has anyone tried running a gluon-mobile app on Android 8.0 (Oreo)? I have a OnePlus5T and tried installing the [fifty-state app](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/fifty-states) with latest source from GitHub and get little boxes where text should be. Any suggestions on how to fix this?
Thanks!

**Phone Info**

```
Android version: 8.0.0 OxygenOS 
version: 5.0.4 
Kernel version: 4.4.78-perf+, OnePlus@ubuntu-143#1 
Build number: ONEPLUS A5010_43_180223
```

[image]

**Android Monitor**

```
03-05 19:45:24.288 18401-18401/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class android.support.multidex.MultiDex failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:24.288 18401-18401/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Common causes for lock verification issues are non-optimized dex code
03-05 19:45:24.288 18401-18401/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: and incorrect proguard optimizations.
03-05 19:45:24.295 18401-18401/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/linker: /data/app/com.gluonhq.fiftystates--tXfak4yY20qjUVzslCYOQ==/lib/arm/libactivity.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libactivity.so"
03-05 19:45:24.489 18401-18401/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:24.494 18401-18674/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:24.502 18401-18675/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:24.519 18401-18675/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:24.526 18401-18678/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/linker: /data/app/com.gluonhq.fiftystates--tXfak4yY20qjUVzslCYOQ==/lib/arm/libprism_es2_monocle.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libprism_es2_monocle.so"
03-05 19:45:24.527 18401-18678/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:24.532 18401-18678/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/linker: /data/app/com.gluonhq.fiftystates--tXfak4yY20qjUVzslCYOQ==/lib/arm/libglass_monocle.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libglass_monocle.so"
03-05 19:45:24.533 18401-18678/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.AcceleratedScreen failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:24.556 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/System.err:  vsync: false vpipe: true
03-05 19:45:24.557 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class javafx.application.Application failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:24.574 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:24.754 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class javafx.scene.Scene$1 failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:24.758 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/linker: /data/app/com.gluonhq.fiftystates--tXfak4yY20qjUVzslCYOQ==/lib/arm/libjavafx_font.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libjavafx_font.so"
03-05 19:45:24.759 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/System.err: Loading FontFactory com.sun.javafx.font.freetype.FTFactory
03-05 19:45:24.759 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/System.err: Subpixel: enabled
03-05 19:45:24.763 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/linker: /data/app/com.gluonhq.fiftystates--tXfak4yY20qjUVzslCYOQ==/lib/arm/libjavafx_font_freetype.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libjavafx_font_freetype.so"
03-05 19:45:24.765 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/System.err: Freetype2 Loaded (version 2.5.0)
03-05 19:45:24.765 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/System.err: LCD support Enabled
03-05 19:45:24.767 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$CacheContainer failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:25.005 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/System.err: Temp file created: /data/user/0/com.gluonhq.fiftystates/cache/+JXF1325095089927391736.tmp
03-05 19:45:25.012 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFile failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:25.019 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/System.err: Temp file created: /data/user/0/com.gluonhq.fiftystates/cache/+JXF7512222163375685761.tmp
03-05 19:45:25.028 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/System.err: Temp file created: /data/user/0/com.gluonhq.fiftystates/cache/+JXF8853061522840412537.tmp
03-05 19:45:25.037 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/System.err: Temp file created: /data/user/0/com.gluonhq.fiftystates/cache/+JXF5121560912934163568.tmp
03-05 19:45:25.119 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class javafx.scene.image.Image failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:25.129 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorage failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:25.166 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerPaintListener failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:25.262 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayoutFactory failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:25.266 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:25.403 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/System.err: File not found: /system/etc/system_fonts.xml
03-05 19:45:25.864 18401-18679/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:26.623 18401-18678/com.gluonhq.fiftystates W/zygote: Class com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer failed lock verification and will run slower.
03-05 19:45:31.834 18401-18401/com.gluonhq.fiftystates E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 2.625, touchXs0 = 1690
03-05 19:45:31.868 18401-18401/com.gluonhq.fiftystates E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 2.625, touchXs0 = 1690
03-05 19:45:31.891 18401-18401/com.gluonhq.fiftystates E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 2.625, touchXs0 = 1690
03-05 19:45:31.892 18401-18401/com.gluonhq.fiftystates E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 2.625, touchXs0 = 1690
```

Comment: I don't think it is related to Android 8, but to the OnePlus device itself. The OnePlus 3 didn't show Roboto Medium, and replacing it with `OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf`worked.  See this [commit](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/commit/ac63be3d199ecead45901a5d87d44012576c37f0) and try to use `OpenSans-regular.ttf`?

Comment: I did a quick test of just changing the .css file .root element to include: `-fx-font-family: 'Open Sans';` and that works (except in a few places)! I'll try the full code solution you provided when I have time and let you know if it also works. Thanks!

Comment: I had a chance to try out your solution and it works fine on my device, but I did have to remove the @font-face section from my _sans.css files.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks José for pointing me in the right direction. Ultimately I was able to fix the fonts on my OnePlus5T by just adding the below to my main .css file, no java changes needed :-)

```css
.app-bar > .title-box > .label,
.dialog > .container > .dialog-title,
.button, .check-box, .label, .text-field,
.header, .footer, .list-cell, .text-area {
    -fx-font-family: 'san-serif';
}

.icon-text {
    -fx-font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
```