# Special characters are displayed

Tags: gluon-mobile

I have special characters when I run my application on Android (One plus 5). When launched ondesktop it is OK.

I use the maven command as described in the gluon doc: mvn -Pandroid client:build client:package

Does anyone knwow what could cause the problem ?

[image]

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122897/gluon-mobile-no-fonts-on-android-8-0-oreo-oneplus5t-phone).

Comment: Thanks José it work by adding the good instructions in css file